# Is Spock's use of 'fascinating' unique?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, spock

In one episode of TOS, Spock explains his use of his favorite term 'fascinating': "I reserve the use of the term fascinating for the unexpected."  Is this something common to Vulcans (eg do we ever see Sarek say 'fascinating' in similar circumstances), or is Spock the only one to use fascinating in this particular way?

Comment: As far as I remember, Sarek and other vulcans did not use this word frequently (if they even used it).

Comment: Interestingly enough, Data seems to use it pretty often too, in the exact same manner. Then again, he may have read up on Spock's own use of the word, so...

Comment: @Zibbobz, As I recall, Data typically says "intriguing" .  He did say "fascinating" and used the Vulcan neck pinch in Unification when he actually meets Spock. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unification_II_(episode)

Comment: A likely avenue for answering this question would be to search through the scripts of Voyager to see how often Tuvok uses the word.

Comment: I always liked it when Bone said "To coin a phrase, fascinating" (in Who Mourns for Adonis). It was a nice way of poking fun at Spock's favourite expression :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a suprisingly common expression. Spock, The EMH, Tuvok, Janeway, Chakotay and Torres all use it in precisely the same way, usually without irony when confronted by something genuinely new and interesting.

With regards to *Vulcan* use of the term, Tuvok seems to be the only other Vulcan we see using it. In the Voyager episode "[Gravity](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/511.htm)", he says it in an almost identical way to Spock, complete with signature eyebrow lift.

> **PARIS:** *It won't do us any good. Every time I transmit a signal, it gets bounced back by the distortion field that pulled us down here. It
>   looks like we fell into some kind of gravity well. As far as I can
>   tell this planet is a part of an entire solar system that is stuck in
>   a pocket of subspace.*
>
> **TUVOK: Fascinating.**

Like Spock, he seems to reserve it for genuinely mind-boggling circumstances such as Kes suddenly demonstrating powerful pyrokenetic abilities in the episode [Cold Fire](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/206.htm);

> **KES:** *He showed me how to use the fire in my mind.* (The water boils.)
>
> **TUVOK:** **Fascinating.**

He also uses the express in a similar fashion (usually without irony) in a wide selection of Voyager episodes including [Year of Hell](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/407.htm), [Mortal Coil](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/410.htm), [Distant Origin](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/318.htm), [The Raven](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/405.htm) and [Hope and Fear](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/423.htm)

Comment: There are real-world parallels, by the by.  A large number of IT professionals mutter 'Interesting' when confronted by software that is working in an unusual way (as has been pointed out to me by any number of frustrated non-IT people).